# Make test avoid relying on real time

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, thread-safety

I have two functions in my queue:

```
    void push(const T& object)
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
      queue.emplace(object);
      conditionVariable.notify_all();
    }

T waitAndPeek()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        conditionVariable.wait(lock, [&] {
            return !queue.empty();
        });
        return queue.front();
    }
```

And now I have such a test(GoogleTest):

```
    std::thread t{[this] {
        EXPECT_EQ(queue.waitAndPeek(), 66);
    }};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(3000ms);
    queue.push(66);
    t.join();
```

Do you have any idea how to make that this test would not rely on the real time? I would like not to wait 2000ms.

Comment: just don't wait for 3 seconds? In general adding sleeps to make your tests work is quite fragile

Comment: Just remove the `sleep_for` line. Condition variable will wait until that condition is satisfied.

Comment: I don't see why this test would fail without sleep. You are waiting correctly on a predicate, so regardless of which action takes place first (push, or peek), you are ok.

Comment: @pptaszni I assume the sleep is there to ensure that the queue is empty at the point `waitAndPeek` is called to test that it works. Without the sleep it's quite likely that the `push` happens first

Comment: Sorry, I didnt specify it. I want push to be called after waitAndPeek' mutex lock. I want to test that waitAndPeek is working fine when pushed after waitAndPeek started waiting.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to test the case where push() is called after wait() has blocked.

One way would be to introduce a side channel for the test to know that wait() has started:

```
bool is_waiting() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    return is_waiting_;
}

T waitAndPeek() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    is_waiting_ = true;
    conditionVariable.wait(lock, [&] {
        return !queue.empty();
    });
    is_waiting_ = false;
    return queue.front();
}
```

Then instead of the sleep have a busy loop:

```
while (!queue.is_waiting()) {}
```

Another approach that keeps the sleep, but reduces the problem would be to invert the threads of execution such that the main test thread calls waitAndPeek() while the auxiliary thread pushes:

```
std::thread t{[this] {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    queue.push(66);
}};
EXPECT_EQ(queue.waitAndPeek(), 66);
t.join();
```

This is less intrusive than the first approach, but still might require a tiny sleep. The sleep time can be reduced compared to the first case, because here we rush into wait() ASAP first, and then wait for the push while in the original test it takes more time until wait() is called: the thread needs to spawn, a context switch happens, and only then it goes into wait().

Note that some form of sleeping might be required e.g. if you run on a single core busy CI instance, so for a busy loop you could also consider adding a tiny sleep or a thread_yield() call.